# How to check if a drive is mapped to a particular network shared drive

Tags: batch-file

Consider I want to map a drive with a shared network drive through a script (batch), I need to map
eg: `T:` to `\\192.168.1.2\network` but when it is already mapped eg: `T: ->` `\\192.168.1.2\network` I don't want to map it again,

I have tried the below snippet were it only maps for the first time, when there is a change in the shared drive it does not do the remapping, can anyone tell what went wrong in the code snippet and how to resolve.

The problem is when I change from `\\192.168.1.2\network` to `\\192.168.1.6\network` it only check if `T:\Jboss` is mapped and it does not do the disconnect and remap with `\\192.168.1.6\network` , one more thing is both `\\192.168.1.2\network` as well as `\\192.168.1.6\network` has same direcotry `Jboss`

```
if exist T:\Jboss (
echo  already T:\Jboss exists
)
if not exist T:\Jboss (
echo  disconnect T:
net use T: /delete
echo  connected T: to network
net use T: \\192.168.1.2\network\persistent:no
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to explicitly check, if a certain drive letter is mapped to a certain network resource:
execute `net use`, filter for the drive letter, filter that line again for the resource, redirect the output to `nul`. (much better than to check for a file or directory that may also exist in another resource)

```
net use |find " T: "|find " \\192.168.1.2\network ">nul && (
  echo already connected
) || (
  echo not yet connected
)
```

`&&` executes as "if previous command was successful, then..."
`||` executes as "if previous command failed, then..."

Answer (score 0):

`net use T:` also returns the current connection status:

> ```cmd
> >>> net use T:
> Local name        T:
> Remote name       \\192.168.1.2\network
> Resource type     Disk
> Status            Connected
> # Opens           1
> # Connections     1
> The command completed successfully.
> ```

You can filter for the `Status` value to retrieve the connection status:

```cmd
net use T: | find "Status" | find "Connected" > nul 2>&1 || (
    net T: /DELETE
    net use T: \\192.168.1.2\network
)
```